# Get-SPSite fails to return all site collections for a content database

Tags: site-collection, backup, restore

I have 3 content databases spread over 2 servers (A & B) called:

- A1
- B1
- B2

I wanted to move a site collection from A1 to B1.  As they are on different servers, I backed up, removed the site and restored, but made a mistake and it was published to B2 instead.

I'm trying to move a site collection from B2 to B1, but kept getting the error that

> The site collection being moved and the destination content database
>   must be on the same database server.

Now this makes it seem that SharePoint thinks the site collection is still on A1.  But, through the Central Administration GUI I can see that the site is listed on B2.  I then run Get-SPSite on A1 and confirm it's gone, but when I turn Get-SPSite on B2 I don't see the site there.

From Central Administration, I can see that the site lists its content database as B2.  I can also look at the "Current Number of Site Collections" for each content database and they reflect what I'd expect: A1's total count went down by 1 after the migration and B2's count went up by 1.  If I count the number of site collections returned for B2 after running Get-SPSite it is 1 short of the total count listed in the Central Administration tool.

What could be causing this?

**Update**

Well there's one more important clue.  Get-SPSite is working today, now it shows that hidden site.  To me this is clear evidence that one of SharePoint's nightly jobs needed to run to update Get-SPSite, but I'm not sure which one.  Any ideas?  Ideally, if this happens again I'd like the option of manually runnign the job.